# Pointer(long) is not public in com.sun.jna.Pointer; Cannot be accessed from outside package

Tags: java, jna

I am creating a program in which I am getting Title of Window in focus and Process Id of particular Window Title. All Works well. But in the line

```
Pointer zero=new Pointer(0);
```

There is a warning showing that "Pointer(long) is not public in com.sun.jna.Pointer; Cannot be accessed from outside package." . I am not getting any solution to solve it. Please help me out.

```
public class Main extends SecurityManager
{
  public static int brojac = 0;
  public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary
  {
    User32 instance = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);
    HWND GetForegroundWindow();  // add this
    int  GetWindowTextA (HWND hWnd, byte[] lpString, int nMaxCount);
    boolean EnumWindows(WinUser.WNDENUMPROC lpEnumFunc, Pointer arg);
    int GetWindowThreadProcessId(HWND hwnd, IntByReference pid);
  }
  public interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary 
  {
    Kernel32 INSTANCE = (Kernel32)Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32.class);
    public Pointer OpenProcess(int dwDesiredAccess, boolean bInheritHandle, int dwProcessId);
    public int GetTickCount();
  };

  public interface psapi extends StdCallLibrary
  {
    psapi INSTANCE = (psapi)Native.loadLibrary("psapi", psapi.class);
    int GetModuleFileNameExA (Pointer process, Pointer hModule, byte[] lpString, int nMaxCount);

  };

  public static String getModuleFilename(HWND hwnd)
  {

    byte[] exePathname = new byte[512];
    Pointer zero = new Pointer(0);
    IntByReference pid = new IntByReference();
    User32.instance.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, pid);
    System.out.println("PID is " + pid.getValue());
    Pointer process = Kernel32.INSTANCE.OpenProcess(1040, false, pid.getValue());
    int result = psapi.INSTANCE.GetModuleFileNameExA(process, zero, exePathname, 512);
    System.out.println("===========module is " + result);
    String text = Native.toString(exePathname).substring(0, result);
    return text;
 }
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
 {
   final User32 user32 = User32.instance; 
   user32.EnumWindows(new WNDENUMPROC() {
   int count = 0;
   @Override
   public boolean callback(HWND hWnd, Pointer arg1) 
   {

     byte[] windowText = new byte[512];
     HWND hwnd = User32.instance.GetForegroundWindow(); // then you can call it!
     User32.instance.GetWindowTextA(hwnd, windowText, 1024);
     String wtext=(Native.toString(windowText));
     System.out.println("Found window with text===" + hWnd + ", total=== " + ++count
                  + " Text:== " + wtext);
     wtext =  getModuleFilename(hWnd);
     System.out.println("##############                 " + wtext);
     return true;
   } }, null);

}
}
```

Comment: `null` is in most cases equivalent to `new Pointer(0)`.  Why do you need a `Pointer` object with native value zero?

Answer (score 0):

I can not reproduce your warning; using JNA version 4.1.0 the code works a expected. Although it doesn't really make sense (implicitly) calling `hWnd.toString()` in your second last message starting with "Found window with text".